# Get Button to move with cells in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, button

I have a macro in Excel which inserts a new, pre-determined row into a spreadsheet. As part of that process, it inserts a button in the final column, which is programmed to run a macro to perform a specific action on that row.

It is frequently required to sort the worksheet to rearrange the data, but I am finding that when I do so the buttons do not move with their associated row, and the actions become all mixed up.

I have tried setting the properties of the buttons to 'XLMove' but it doesn't work - when the data is sorted the buttons stay put in their original cell.

**How can I anchor the button to the cell that they were originally inserted into, so that the sorting moves the buttons as well?**

```
Dim btn As Button
Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(1173, 257.25, 41.25, 23.25)

With btn
    .Placement = xlMove
    .OnAction = "ButtonRow"
    .Characters.Text = "Action!"
    .Left = ActiveCell.Left
    .Top = ActiveCell.Top
End With
```

Comment: Which version of Excel? Your code works for me.

Comment: With the way you are doing it, it does work with me. Is there a possibility that the cell itself, to which you anchored the button, is not included in the range where you apply the sorting? (p.s.: I tested it on Excel 2007)

Comment: Tested it on Excel 2010 - it works, unfortunately I'd mis-defined the range for the sort.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
With btn
    .Placement = xlMove
    .OnAction = "ButtonRow"
    .Characters.Text = "Action!"
    .Left = ActiveCell.Left
    .Top = ActiveCell.Top
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(.Name).LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
End With
```